# How to define users id in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make unban command. The problem is that I don't know how to define a user id before I define it. Error: `ReferenceError: userId is not defined`. I need to find out if the user is banned or not. And to find out if it's banned, I need a "user id", which I get a few lines down. I hope someone solves this mystery.

```
const { ReactionCollector, User } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: "Odbanuje člena.",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, chalk){
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });


        const channelId = client.channels.cache.get('802649418087530537');
        const author = message.author;
        const userName = message.mentions.users.first();
        
        if(!message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")){
            message.reply('Nemáš potřebné permisse!')
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            });
            console.log(chalk.red('[ERROR] (./commands/unban/) Missing "BAN_MEMBERS" permission'));
            return;
        } else if(!args[1]){
            message.reply('`!unban <člen> <důvod>`')
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            });
            console.log(chalk.red('[ERROR] (./commands/unban/) Missing args[1]'));
            return;
        }
    
        const banList = await message.guild.fetchBans();
        const bannedUser = banList.find(user => user.id === userId);

        if(bannedUser){
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
            let userId = message.guild.members.cache.get(userName.id);

            const botId = '799652033509457940';
            
            const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#2ca819')
            .setTitle('Unban')
            .addFields(
                {name:'Člen:', value:`${userId}`},
                {name:'Udělil:', value:`${author}`},
                {name:'Důvod:', value:`${reason}`},
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            channelId.send(banEmbed)

            await userId.unban()

            console.log(chalk.green(`[INFO] (./commands/unban/) User "${userId.user.username}" was unbanned"`));
        }else{
            message.reply('Tohoto člena nemůžu najít.')
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            });

            console.log(chalk.red(`[ERROR] (./commands/unban/) Can not find target`));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should probably clarify that you are working with discord in the question title and body :)

Comment: Why don't you move `let userId = ...` above `const bannedUser = ...`?

Comment: Because if I do, then `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.